# Is it acceptable to format output for view inside a hibernate entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, architecture

Is it acceptable to perform formatting for the view in a hibernate entity?

Ex, I have a Merchant entity that holds a set of MerchantLocation entities. Each MerchantLocation in the set holds a Location object.

Lets say I retreive a fully populated list of Merchants from the DB and in the view I need to display the list of Merchants and beside each Merchant I need to display a comma seperatd list of their Location ids.

Where would I put the logic to get the location ids? In the entity? The controller? Create some kind of view object in the service layer?

```
Merchant
     |
     |--Set<MerchantLocation>
                 |-Location
                 |-Location
                 |-Location
                 |-Location etc...
```

I am using Spring MVC if it makes any difference.

Comment: When using MVC architecture, all the data manipulation goes into Model, regardless of the framework (Spring MVC, Struts 2, JSF or whatever) you use. The data is passed from the Model to the Controller, and then to the View. The view will decide how to display the data, not the Model.

Comment: So, should I build an object specific to this view in the model? Basically convert the Entity into a view object?

Comment: Currently I just retrieve an entity from the DB that has a couple helper methods in it used for formatting some of that entities properties specifically for the view.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `CommaSeparatedListHelper` in the view layer and pass it a list of respected `Location` objects. `CommaSeparatedListHelper` should receive something like `List<Object>` and use `toString()` method of all passed object to build the list.

The logic to get `Location` objects from `Merchant` ones can reside in the model.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this, but instead of creating a helper, I just created a custom tag that took the list as a parameter and printed it out.